# Создание одномерного статического массива в C++ из исходного

Tags: c++, массивы

Дан массив z0, z1,…, zn-1. Найти число элементов этого массива, значения которых принадлежат отрезку [c, d] и предшествуют последнему по порядку элементу массива с отрицательным значением.

Интересует только функция обработки массива.

Comment: Нас всех тоже очень интересует функция обработки (нет), а в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Комментарий `написать самой` лично мне намекает о том, что автора приведенного кода зовут не Андрей. Или написан он был не для Андрея. Сделайте уж хоть что-нибудь сами:) "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу"

Comment: Тем более, не очень понятен даже принцип построения результирующей последовательности. Но тут могу ошибаться, либо Вы с индексами напутали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получается, что первая половина результата совпадает со второй половиной источника, а вторая половина результата - перевернутая первая половина источника.

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 3 4 5 2 1 0
```

Сделайте цикл на `n` шагов, и в нём присваивайте элементам результата элементы источника с нужным индексом.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    d[i]  = c[i + что?]; //первая половина
    d[i + n]  = c[что-то_другое? - i];   //вторая половина
}
```